# txt file to array (NO LISTS)

Tags: java, arrays, java-io

I am trying to read in a file with 81 integers and populate an array with those 81 integers so I check the numbers for validity.

```
public static int[][] ReadIn () {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a filename: ");
        int[][] grid = new int[9][9];
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                grid[i][j] = input.nextInt();


        File file = new File(input);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String st;
        while((st = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(st);

        return grid;
    }
```

My problem is when I read in the file from the user I get an error

```
CheckSudokuSolution.java:24: error: no suitable constructor found for File(Scanner)
        File file = new File(input);
                    ^
    constructor File.File(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Scanner cannot be converted to String)
    constructor File.File(URI) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Scanner cannot be converted to URI)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

I'm not sure why this error occurs or how to resolve it.

Comment: OK, NO LISTS THEN. You need to get a string from the `Scanner`, not use the `Scanner` itself, e.g. `new File(input.next())`.

Comment: try `scanner.nextLine()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int[][] readASolution(String filename) {
        int[][] grid = new int[9][9];

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            int i = 0;

            while(sc.hasNext()) {
                int j = 0;
                String line = sc.nextLine();

                for( int x = 0; x < line.length(); x++) 
                    if( Character.isDigit(line.charAt(x)) ) {
                        grid[i][j] = Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(x)); 
                        j++;
                    }
                if (i == 9) break;
                i++; 
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e ) { 
            System.err.println( "Error: " + e );
        }
        return grid;
    }
```

This is a correct solution I came up with for anyone else dealing with this type of problem.